# Passing multiple buffers as ArgumentBuffers in metal

Tags: macos, metal

I have to pass multiple buffers to my Metal compute kernel. Something like this:

```
const device uint32_t *a [[buffer(0)]];
const device uint32_t *b [[buffer(1)]];
const device uint32_t *c [[buffer(2)]];
const device uint8_t *d [[buffer(3)]];
const device uint8_t *e [[buffer(4)]];
```

These arrays can have variable sizes so, I cannot use `<array>`. So, I was trying to use ArgumentBuffers to pass all these buffers as one ArgumentBuffer to the compute kernel.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct Arguments 
{
    const device uint32_t *a [[buffer(0)]];
    const device uint32_t *b [[buffer(1)]];
    const device uint32_t *c [[buffer(2)]];
    const device uint8_t *d [[buffer(3)]];
    const device uint8_t *e [[buffer(4)]];
} Arguments;

kernel void
myKernel(device Arguments &arguments [[ buffer(ComputeBufferInput) ]],
                texture2d<half, access::write> outTexture [[texture(ComputeBufferOutput)]],
                uint2                          gid         [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{

}
```

I get a compilation failure telling me

> Type 'device Arguments &' is not valid for attribute 'buffer'

How can I pass buffers to kernels in ArgumentBuffers?
Is it possible to pass buffers like this in ArgumentBuffer for metal kernels?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turned out you can only have buffers in an ArgumentBuffers, if the Deployment target of your application is 10.13. You cannot have buffers in applications having deployment targets less than 10.13.